# Typescript and Angular Initialise objects in the constrcutror of the class, from other class type

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I have a simple case which just makes me nuts.

```
module PaymentType {
    export interface IPaymentTypeScope extends ng.IScope {
        PaymentTypeApprovals: PaymentTypeApproval[];
        FormatDate: Function;

   ....

        AuditTrailDialogObject: AuditTrailDialog;
.....
    }

    export class PaymentTypeController {

        private _: UnderscoreStatic;
        private _scope: IPaymentTypeScope;
        private _log: ng.ILogService;
        private _q: ng.IQService;
        private _paymentTypeService: IPaymentTypeService;
        private _sce: ng.ISCEService;

        constructor($scope: IPaymentTypeScope, $log: ng.ILogService, paymentTypeService: PaymentType.IPaymentTypeService, $q: ng.IQService, $sce: ng.ISCEService) {
            this._paymentTypeService = paymentTypeService;
            this._scope = $scope;
            this._log = $log;
            this._q = $q;
            this._sce = $sce;



      ....
            this.InitialiseScope();
        }

        InitialiseScope = () => {
            this._scope.AuditTrailDialogObject = new AuditTrailDialog();
        }

      .......
```

I am trying to have an object of type AuditTrailDialog inside a method in the class. In that method I plan to set some properties of that dialog and then use it for binding.
This code gives me an error - undefined is not a function in the point of initialising the object.
If I do not initialise the object, I got an error - Cannot set property 'Title' of undefined.
Please help what should I do so I can use the object of another class in my class and then use it for angular binding in the controller.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> This code gives me an error - undefined is not a function in the point of initialising the object.

This is a runtime error that has to do with how you load your JavaScript. This depends on additional context *surrounding your code* no presented in the answer. I recommend you use something like `requirejs` and compile typescript with `--module amd` instead of manually loading (seemingly incorrectly) the generated javascript. Also recommend against `--out` / the `module` keyword as documented here : https://github.com/TypeStrong/atom-typescript/blob/master/docs/out.md